# Insert some values from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

i have these two tables...

Table1:

```
IDPlayer  int
```

Table2:

```
ID_event int (Autoincrement - probably bad)
IDPlayer2  int
participate  bit
```

and i have this command, but i don´t know, How do I do that for 1 insert is 1 event...

```
Insert into Table2 (ID_IDPlayer2) 
Select Table1.IDPlayer
FROM Table1
```

OUTPUTS:

```
event  player  participate  
1   1   False
2   2   False
3   3   False
4   4   False
5   1   False
6   2   False
7   3   False
8   4   False
```

But i want this:

```
event  player  participate  
    1   1   False
    1   2   False
    1   3   False
    1   4   False
    2   1   False
    2   2   False
    2   3   False
    2   4   False
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is id_event meant to filter by? Do you need a filter at all or just to take all the Id's from one table and put them in another?

Comment: Maybe add a couple of rows of each table as a sample and what your end result should look like...

Comment: very confusing to understand what you want ,,plz explain furthur..

Comment: I want take all idPlayer from table1 and put to Table2 into same ID_event .....event is the training of players...ID_event is for example number of training and ID_Player2 is all players on the training..

Comment: INSERT into Table2(columns name) SELECT 'those columns that you want to insert'
FROM table1
WHERE 'your condition',,,You have to make a query like this,,it's simple but your database structure is very complex and freak as well.difficult to understand.

Comment: I have querry like this...but i need each other training have different number..

Comment: please post some sample data and desired output so it will be easy to understand and answer

Comment: I edited first post...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server,

You can keep using auto increment but you may want to enable identity insertion for 'event' column:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table2 ON;
```

After that, you can insert players into table 2 for a specific event.
Next sentence will insert all players into event 1:

```
Insert into Table2 (ID_event , ID_IDPlayer2) 
Select 1, Table1.IDPlayer
FROM Table1
```

Nevertheless I wouldn't use autoincrement for this. I think you should keep a second table to store events (EventsTable), keep autoincrement there if you want, and make Table2.ID_Event be a reference (as foreign key) to EventsTable.ID;

A solution based on your requisites is to use a trigger. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Events (id INT); #Events table

CREATE TABLE Table2  (ID_event INT, IDPlayer2 INT); #Events and player relation table

CREATE TABLE Table1  (IDPlayer2 INT); #Players table
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (4);


CREATE TRIGGER NewEvent ON Events AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT inserted.id, IDPlayer2 FROM Table1, inserted;
END

INSERT INTO Events VALUES (1001);
INSERT INTO Events VALUES (1002);

SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

Comment: Yes, i create this table, but how i do if i create new event in new event table ...make this value in Table2 automatic...?

Comment: So, what you whant is to autoinsert all players into Table2 after each new event insertion into a table containing events?

Comment: Then, you can create a trigger which inserts all players of Table1 grouped by Event after event insertion:

    CREATE TRIGGER NewEvent ON Events AFTER INSERT AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT inserted.id, IDPlayer2
        FROM Table1, inserted;
    END

Comment: Now it write this error: 'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Comment: Select the trigger creation sentence (from "CREATE TRIGGER" to "END" both included) and run just that sentence (F5 if you are using SQL Server).